# How to paginate without fetching the entire table?

Tags: python, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am trying to **paginate** the fetched data from my *table*(from *Remote Database on **Azure***) as can be seen in the code, below:

```
    import json
    import pyodbc

    # Includes other imports

    def query_db(query):
        """
        Function that queries the required table in the DB
        """

        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; \
                               SERVER=db.database.windows.net; \
                               DATABASE=DB; UID=id; PWD=pwd')
        cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        cur = cnxn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)

        # Fetches the entire table ## This is causing the lagg
        r = [dict( (cur.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row) ) for row in cur.fetchall()]

        cur.connection.close()

        return(r)

    @api_view(['GET'])
    def get(request):
        paginator = PageNumberPagination()
        my_query = query_db("select * from Client_Table")

        result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(my_query, request)
        json_output = json.dumps(result_page, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        return paginator.get_paginated_response(json_output)
```

The Problem here being: I am fetching the entire table first, and then paginating it. How do I *Paginate*, without having to fetch the entire table ?
*NOTE: I am not using Django Models*

Comment: If me, I would rather fetchall from the remote db and cache in redis.

Comment: Interesting idea (although I have never used any caching library or Redis). But then how would this work ? I have about 5000 records in my table, and I am paginating for 15 records per page. What would I be caching ( if I were to cache ) ?

Comment: seems you might try to opt for fetchone() after running the query for how much of the table you want ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: I think use `Model.objects.count()` to get the total_page and `Model.objects.all()[:15]` to limit the query may be work for you.

Comment: @WaketZheng I am not using Django Models!!

Comment: @timi95 I have already read that documentation. Can you tell me more about how exactly should I use fetchone() ?

Comment: well, my naive instinct is to attempt it something like this : https://pastebin.com/gV89SBdt

Comment: @timi95 I checked the link. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to call the filtered data from the DB, as it is paginated you can call the API with skip and limit logic for parsing the next or preciding data.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY id OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

e.g
In starting you want first 10 ROWS then from your application pass the param
of skip=0&limit=10

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Now if you click next and want next 10 ROWS, you just need to pass the params of skip=10&limit=10

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY id OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Similarly you can change the result per page also by passing the limit as whatever you want.

As per your code, I expect you are using GET Method

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get(request):
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    skip=request.params.get('skip')
    limit=request.params.get('limit')
    query = "SELECT * FROM Client_table ORDER BY ID OFFSET "+ skip + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + limit+" ROWS ONLY"
    my_query = query_db(query)
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(my_query, request)
    json_output = json.dumps(result_page, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

    return paginator.get_paginated_response(json_output)
```

Comment: Thats the solution that I was looking for. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: How am I supposed to get total number of records for showing total number of Pages with this answer?