# How to paginate aws lambda response to rest api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I hope you can help me on how to paginate response from Lambda Function to api gateway.
I have an api gateway as lambda function trigger.
POST request, triggers a lambda (written in Python) that performs a query to a database, transform the data and return this data back to API.

Mi API POST method integration request has following parameters:

- Integration type: Lambda Function
- Use Lambda Proxy integration: YES
- Rest of fields as default.

I want to paginate the API response but I can't find how to do it.
My lambda returns query details to the api as a big JSON. But I want that JSON limit can be 20 items per page.
Could you please guide me on how to implement it? Thanks

Comment: Do u want api gateway to provide pagination on behalf of your lambda? That is not an option. You would have to do pagination in your Lambda. by taking query parameters for pagination from api caller

Comment: thanks for your response @mongeshmadhavan. But it I do that way, how I tell the lambda to paginate the response? I have never do something similar so I am a bit lost

Comment: you can check answer in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666063/how-to-paginate-without-fetching-the-entire-table